# how can we user regular expression for element with bracket in dropdown and after it reloads there is no bracket for the dropdown input text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

[selection from dropdown ,the string has bracket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVXbU.png)
After it reloads element from dropdown there is no bracket

i.e:-  Adani Electricity Mumbai Limited - (RELI00000MUM03)
--select this from dropdown
and after reloading it changes to Adani Electricity Mumbai Limited - RELI00000MUM03

How can we handle the bracket with string matching

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//md-autocomplete[@id='billerAutoComplete']//md-autocomplete-wrap//md-input-container//input")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement biller;

public void Billerlist() throws InterruptedException {
    biller.sendKeys("Adani Electricity Mumbai Limited - (RELI00000MUM03)");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    biller.click();
    biller.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    biller.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}
```

Also tried,

```
public void selectBiller(String Biller) {
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(biller)); biller.click();
  log.debug(biller.getText()); waitForObject(1000);
  
  List<WebElement> billerOptions =
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//md-autocomplete-parent-scope//span"));
  log.debug(billerOptions.size());
 
  for (WebElement option :billerOptions) { 
  log.debug(option.getText()); 
   if (option.getText().contains(Biller)) {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(option)); 
       option.click();
      //option.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
      } 
  }
```

Comment: Add screenshot of your problem

Comment: adding options.SendKeys(Keys, Down)